# Firebase authentication on App initilisation

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

This is works:

```
console.log('User ID: ' + user.id + ', Provider: ' + user.provider);
```

but this one is not:

```
$scope.authenticated.currentUser = user.id;
```

My goal here is to take to take some of the authentication variables (Email+UserID) and then use them to access a profile node ON firebase. On initialization I want the username, email, and a few other things I need for the app.

```
crossfitApp.controller('globalIdCtrl', ["$scope",'defautProfileData','$q', function ($scope,defautProfileData,$q) {

var  dataRef =   new Firebase("https://glowing-fire-5401.firebaseIO.com");

$scope.authenticated={
                        currentUser: $scope.authemail,
                        emailAddress: "",
                        settings: "",
                    };

var chatRef = new Firebase('https://<YOUR-FIREBASE>.firebaseio.com');
var auth = new FirebaseSimpleLogin(chatRef, function(error, user) {
  if (error) {
    // an error occurred while attempting login
    switch(error.code) {
      case 'INVALID_EMAIL':
      case 'INVALID_PASSWORD':
      default:
    }
  } else if (user) {
    // user authenticated with Firebase
    console.log('User ID: ' + user.id + ', Provider: ' + user.provider);

      $scope.authenticated.currentUser = user.id ;//

  } else {
    // user is logged out
  }
});

}]);  //GlobaldCtrl
```

Comment: What's the problem? You need to provide a clearer explanation of what's wrong. Your post starts with "This is not working... but this one is not." So, neither works? Doesn't work how?

Comment: "This" refers to the subsequent function, likewise "but this one is not:" refers to the next block of code

Comment: The problem isn't what you mean by "this." It's that you say one thing isn't working, then follow it with "but this one is not," meaning neither is working. You don't say *how* either isn't working, so it's impossible to tell what problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: My mistake. The first one works. I  will edit. Sorry for confusion. SO sorry.

Comment: Hi Kris, when you say that it's not working, what error are you receiving?

Comment: No error. I was expecting the function to change the value of $scope.authenticated.currentUser, but it does not. When I run auth.login-- then it actaully works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, you're running into a problem with [Angular's HTML Compiler](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/compiler).

Whenever you use an event like ng-click/ng-submit/etc, Angular fires $scope.$apply(), which checks for any changes to your $scope variables and applies them to the DOM.

Since FirebaseSimpleLogin is not part of Angular's purview, it has no idea that when the callback is fired, you've updated $scope.authenticated.currentUser. This would also explain why it works when you call auth.login(), since you're probably invoking that via an ng-click event somewhere, which would fire a digest check and discover the changes.

If this is indeed the case, you can correct this issue by alerting Angular that it needs to run $apply by using $timeout:

```
crossfitApp.controller('globalIdCtrl', ["$scope",'defautProfileData','$q', '$timeout', function ($scope,defautProfileData,$q, $timeout) {

/* ... */

var auth = new FirebaseSimpleLogin(chatRef, function(error, user) {
  if (error) {
    /* ... */
  } else if (user) {
    $timeout(function() {
       $scope.authenticated.currentUser = user.id ;//
    });
  } else {
    // user is logged out
  }
});
```

Comment: Solved! Thank you. Working now!